# AviarySDK iOS error

Tags: ios, aviary

I use cocoapods and download Aviary SDK from the website and follow all the instructions from website. However, I still get an error below:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFPhotoEditorController", referenced from:

Any idea how to fix it? Is the libAviarySDK.a compiled for 64bit architecture?

Comment: arm64 - are you sure about that? Check your architecture settings.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the library does not have an arm64 compiled binary. You should change your build settings to only build for armv7 and armv7s if you want to continue using this SDK.

If your app requires arm64 support, then you won't be able to use this SDK until its authors provide an arm64 compiled version.

Answer (score 1):

AviarySDK 4.2.1 now supports arm64 architecture.

```
# lipo -info AviarySDK.framework/AviarySDK
Architectures in the fat file: AviarySDK.framework/AviarySDK are: i386 armv7 armv7s arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

aviary 3.3.7 is compatible with iOS7. So i suggest you can try to change Architectures of your project to "Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s)"